# How to detect the current scene in SpriteKit project

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

In my SpriteKit app I've 3 different scenes and I want to set a specific settings for each scene.
I mean I want set visible an AdBanner in MainPage and SomeInfoScene but not in GameScene. How can I do this?
This is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {

        let mainPage = SKScene(fileNamed: "MainPage")!
        mainPage.name = "MainPage"

        let someInfoPage = SKScene(fileNamed: "SomeInfoScene")!
        someInfoPage.name = "SomeInfoScene"

        let gameScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")!
        gameScene.name = "GameScene"

        view.presentScene(mainPage)

        if let currentScene = view.scene {

            if currentScene.name == mainPage.name {

                print("MainPage")
                adBannerView.isHidden = false
            }
            if currentScene.name == someInfoPage.name {

                print("SomeInfoScene")
                adBannerView.isHidden = false
            }
            if currentScene.name == gameScene.name {

                print("GameScene")
                adBannerView.isHidden = true
            }
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: According to this code,  your  last if statement is pointless, current scene will always be `MainPage`

Comment: The `view.presentScene(mainPage)` line presents the `"MainPage"` scene — this is *now* the scene returned by `view.scene`. As such, the code in **[1]** in **[2]** will never be fired. You may need to review your game controller logic...

Comment: Yes, but when I open SomeInfoScene or GameScene should not it run code [1] and [2]?

Comment: I want to set different settings for each scene, how can I do this?

Comment: Hey man, I recommend you open *another* question with this specific issue (and link back to this one for quick reference). You will get better results that way... (and please don't forget to accept/upvote my answer as well). Thanks bro!

Comment: OK I've done it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tracked by [`scene`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview/1520084-scene) property of the [`SKView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview) class. For instance:

```
if let view = self.view as? SKView {
    if let currentScene = view.scene {
        print("Current scene is: \(currentScene)")
    else {
        print("Current scene is nil")
    }
}
```

By the way, your first line really should read:

```
if let view = self.view as? SKView { ...
```

That's the standard/idiomatic way to try a downcast in an `if` statement.

---

**Update**. You also need to set the [`name`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483136-name) property if you are planning to use that in your game code (in the `*.sks` file *or* directly inside your code). For instance:

```
let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "MainPage")!
scene.name = "MainPage"
view.presentScene(scene)
```

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean.

Comment: What do you mean with ... after SKView ?

Comment: @PietroP. because you are asking the wrong question,  you need to assign `name` in your SKS file before your switch can work

Comment: @PauloMattos, that first line is how Apple wrote the template (no idea why)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I guess even Apple engineers are having a hard wrapping their head around Swift *optionals*, haha ;)

Comment: @PauloMattos whoever they have maintaining Sprite kit is just destroying the library, probably some new interns/ junior programmers that they hire who have no understanding of the language/framework and are told to just wing it LOL